# is it possible to change how much page up/page down scroll (either via settings or something I install)?

Tags: macos

I'd love for page down to scroll half as much as it does.

I'd be open to out-of-the-box solutions...

What if it were just in Chrome/Firefox/Safari? I imagine perhaps it wouldn't be too hard to make an extension if I had to...

Or even making a native macOS app to do this. Though I have no experience with such things and am not really sure if it would be doable.

I also use Keyboard Maestro for other things, but I'm not sure if it'd be possible to fire a command that would instantly scroll the desired amount...

Comment: It is dependent on the screen size and chosen zoom size

Comment: It's a big problem. Scroll is exactly 100%, but many websites these days have sticky navigation bars that cover up part of that vertical space, so it's often impossible to see portions of the page if you're limited to the page up/down buttons.